# Why are the results from the keras validation split different from sklearn metrics?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am training a Keras model, and running:

```
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_val))
```

I'm using AUC, precision, and recall as the metrics (also passed to `model.compile`).

However, the validation metrics printed out are better than the ones from sklearn, whose metric values I obtain as:

```py
preds = (model.predict(x_test) > 0.5).astype('int32')
auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, preds)
# similar for the other metrics
```

My questions are:

1. What causes this discrepancy?
2. If I run a different model with the same `validation_data` parameter, would that be an apples-to-apples comparison?
3. Which should I report, or does it not matter as long as I'm consistent?

Comment: Please add code for sklearn. What is the metric? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DevashishPrasad Updated with more details